# how to retrieve less rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have this table:

```
USE [testing]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[table1]    Script Date: 1/02/2014 9:35:13 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [rate] [decimal](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([id], [date], [rate]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A2A600000000 AS DateTime), CAST(12 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([id], [date], [rate]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A2A700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([id], [date], [rate]) VALUES (3, CAST(0x0000A2A800000000 AS DateTime), CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([id], [date], [rate]) VALUES (4, CAST(0x0000A2A900000000 AS DateTime), CAST(56 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO
```

I would like to return the difference in rates between 2 rows, and return 3 rows :

```
-10
1
43
```

What do I have to change on this query?

```
select t1.rate-t2.rate
from table1 t1
join table1 t2 on 
t1.id> t2.id
where (t2.id-t1.id) <=1
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using please?

Comment: Are the ids guaranteed to be consecutive with no gaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, assuming ID's are in the order you want and no gaps:

```
SELECT t1.rate-t2.rate
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table1 t2 
 ON t1.id = t2.id + 1
```

If using SQL Server 2012 you can make use of the `LEAD()` function:

```
SELECT rate - LEAD(rate) OVER (ORDER BY id)
FROM Table1
```

That returns a 4th row with `NULL`, so could use a cte/subquery to limit to the 3 rows with populated values.

Note, if the ID's are not gauranteed to be in the order you want, or if there are gaps between some id's you should use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function (if not using the `LEAD()` version with explicit `ORDER BY`):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) RN
              FROM Table1)
SELECT t1.rate-t2.rate
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 
 ON t1.RN = t2.RN + 1
```

Demo of all 3: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3898/5/0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    T1.rate - T2.rate as rateDiff
FROM table1 T1
  JOIN table1 T2
     ON T1.id = T2.Id + 1
```